# CREATE TABLE AS with SELECT clause throws error in QGIS DB Manager

Tags: qgis, sql, dbmanager

I am not able to run the `CREATE TABLE AS` command in QGIS DB Manager (Win 10, QGIS 3.4.5-Madeira. I am getting the same error in QGIS 2.18 (Win 8).

`Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS CREATE TABLE VV as SELECT 55 AS FF: 1 - near "CREATE": syntax error`

[image]
Here is the error message in a screenshot:

Actually, I see even the following does not work on my Win 10.

```
   CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),       
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Am I missing something in syntax, or the DB manager is missing something?

Comment: In which section in DB Manager are you ? Virtual Layers ? If so, DDL commands are not available.

Comment: It is a *Virtual Layer*. I see the problem now.

Comment: It would be helpful if instead of "I see the problem now," a solution were offered. I'm getting a similar error in DB manager on a non-spatial CSV. I simply need to prepend a zero on a numeric field (that was a text field in google sheets) (so I was trying to create a new text field). I'm in QGIS 3.8, and the Table Manager Plugin doesn't work. Solutions welcome. How do you know what turns into a virtual layer? And how to get a non-virtual layer from a CSV, if you need to alter the table or its contents?

Comment: @MarjorieRoswell, I have added a solution based on the above comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported an sqlite database/layer into the DB Manager (See Menu `Database>DB Manager`). The syntax I used was the following:

```
create table VV as select 55 as GG
```

The following did not work:

```
create table VV as (select 55 as GG)
```

OR

```
create table VV select 55 as GG
```

OR

```
create table VV (select 55 as GG)
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your question?

Comment: Yes probably the first one worked. I have not checked it now